# Select which test to run with Hspec and stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hspec

I've written a series of test, using the [automatic spec discovery](http://hspec.github.io/hspec-discover.html) feature of Hspec. I'm also using [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) as my build tool.

My test directory has the the `Spec.hs` file, along with the test files for the different modules of my application (e.g. `Module0Spec.hs`, `Module1Spec.hs`).

Now, when I start writing a new test module, or when I want to re-run a failed test after code changes, I'd like to be able to run only a given test module.

Is there any way in which either stack or Hspec allow to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2210). I was trying with `--`, however I needed to use `--test-arguments`:

```
stack test --test-arguments "-m "Module0""
```