# Haskell Hspec - only run expensive test on command line flag

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hspec

I want to run an expensive Hspec test only when some flag on the command line is set for `stack test`. I understand that I can use `stack test --test-arguments=...` but what would I use on the command line and how would I carry out the conditional testing in my `Spec.hs`? I can't seem to find a good example elsewhere online.

**EDIT:**  Is it possible to get a test to be skipped when just running `stack test` with no skip specified? Or would this be possible by having another similar specification file with just the expensive test in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`--skip=PATTERN`](http://hspec.github.io/options.html) to skip a test. Other than that, you can check the command line arguments in your own `main` if you don't use automatic test discovery and set the `Config` for [`hspecWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-core-2.4.4/docs/Test-Hspec-Core-Runner.html#v:hspecWith) (the `configSkipPredicate`).

If you want to automatically skip a test without specifying it on the command line you can use a `.hspec` file, see [here](http://hspec.github.io/options.html#specifying-options-in-config-fi%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bles). The you can override the skip by specifying to match the pattern instead on the command line.

Comment: That's great. Is it possible to get a test to be skipped when just running `stack test` with no skip specified? Or would this be possible by having another similar specification file with just the expensive test in?

Comment: You can set the skip in a `.hspec` file, see http://hspec.github.io/options.html#specifying-options-in-config-files.

Comment: To execute `--skip` with `stack test` on the command line you can run `stack test --test-arguments "--skip "PATTERN""`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365402/select-which-test-to-run-with-hspec-and-stack. Because I found this slightly unintuitive.