# How to run an individual test with Stack and Haskell Test.Framework?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm cloning the [haskoin/haskoin-core](https://github.com/haskoin/haskoin-core) repository and making one change to the `stack.yaml` by adding at the end:

```
docker:
    enable: true
```

To run all the tests for `haskoin-core` I'm using

```
stack test haskoin-core:test-haskoin-core
```

What I want to do is run just one test. If this were `HSpec` (which it is not) I'd be running [something like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39365910/15441):

```
stack test --test-arguments -m "Network.Haskoin.Network.Units"
```

Now what I could do is modify the file `haskcoin-core/test/Main.hs` and comment out all the tests I don't want to run. But ya know - there should be a simpler way to run it with just command line parameters. (Mutating the file system goes agains the whole functional grain of Haskell).

I'd also be open to running it with `stack ghci` somehow.

My question is: **How to run an individual test with Stack and Haskell Test.Framework?**

Comment: Try running `stack test --test-arguments "--help"` to discover what kind of options you can pass to the test suite.

Comment: Thanks @sjakobi - that's helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @sjakobi for this answer.

The process is - list the available test commands:

```
stack test --test-arguments "--help" haskoin-core:test-haskoin-core
```

This gives the following result:

```
haskoin-core-0.4.2: test (suite: test-haskoin-core, args: --help)

Usage: test-haskoin-core [OPTIONS]
                   --help                                       show this help message
  -j NUMBER        --threads=NUMBER                             number of threads to use to run tests
                   --test-seed=NUMBER|random                    default seed for test random number generator
  -a NUMBER        --maximum-generated-tests=NUMBER             how many automated tests something like QuickCheck should try, by default
                   --maximum-unsuitable-generated-tests=NUMBER  how many unsuitable candidate tests something like QuickCheck should endure before giving up, by default
  -s NUMBER        --maximum-test-size=NUMBER                   to what size something like QuickCheck should test the properties, by default
  -d NUMBER        --maximum-test-depth=NUMBER                  to what depth something like SmallCheck should test the properties, by default
  -o NUMBER        --timeout=NUMBER                             how many seconds a test should be run for before giving up, by default
                   --no-timeout                                 specifies that tests should be run without a timeout, by default
  -l               --list-tests                                 list available tests but don't run any; useful to guide subsequent --select-tests
  -t TEST-PATTERN  --select-tests=TEST-PATTERN                  only tests that match at least one glob pattern given by an instance of this argument will be run
                   --jxml=FILE                                  write a JUnit XML summary of the output to FILE
                   --jxml-nested                                use nested testsuites to represent groups in JUnit XML (not standards compliant)
                   --plain                                      do not use any ANSI terminal features to display the test run
                   --color                                      use ANSI terminal features to display the test run
                   --hide-successes                             hide sucessful tests, and only show failures


Test suite failure for package haskoin-core-0.4.2
    test-haskoin-core:  exited with: ExitFailure 1
Logs printed to console
```

From that we can build a command to list the tests:

```
stack test --test-arguments "--list-tests" haskoin-core:test-haskoin-core
```

From there we can use this command to glob for a particular test

```
stack test --test-arguments=--select-tests=Bloom*Filter haskoin-core:test-haskoin-core
```

Note the `*` in place of the space, there seems to be [some](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/172) [discussion](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3091) about how to handle spaces in this scenario.

Now this selects the tests we want to run:

```
haskoin-core-0.4.2: test (suite: test-haskoin-core, args: --select-tests=Bloom*Filter)

Binary encoding and decoding of bloom types:
  BloomFilter: [OK, passed 100 tests]
Bloom Filters:
  Bloom Filter Vector 1: [OK]
  Bloom Filter Vector 2: [OK]
  Bloom Filter Vector 3: [OK]

         Properties  Test Cases  Total      
 Passed  1           3           4          
 Failed  0           0           0          
 Total   1           3           4
```

Answer (score 6):

As of mid 2019, I think `stack` has changed.

1. See `--help` for options:

   `stack test --test-arguments "--help"`
2. Do a `--dry-run` to see what tests will run:

   `stack test --test-arguments "--dry-run"`
3. Select tests with `--match`. Note, this alleges glob patterns will work but they don't seem to for me:

   `stack test --test-arguments "--match=foobar"`

AFAICT, `"foobar"` is interpreted like a glob of `*foobar*`, but I can't be explicit about it.

Comment: AFAICT, `"foobar"` is *not* a glob of `*foobar*`.

Comment: Note that if the test name contains whitespace, you need to use `-m "/<test_name>/"` for exact match